# Reusing same javascript with slightly different application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem where I have some code which I want to apply to two slightly different applications, but 75% of the code will be the same. This is where I am with things:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/H6SZ2/6/

```
$(function () {
  var input = $("#loc"),
      lat   = $("#lat"),
      lng   = $("#lng"),
      lastQuery  = null,
      lastResult = null, // new!
      autocomplete;

  function processLocation(callback) { // accept a callback argument
    var query = $.trim(input.val()),
        geocoder;

    // if query is empty or the same as last time...
    if( !query || query == lastQuery ) {
      callback(lastResult); // send the same result as before
      return; // and stop here
    }

    lastQuery = query; // store for next time

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ address: query }, function(results, status) {
      if( status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
        lat.val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
        lng.val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        lastResult = true; // success!
      } else {
        alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative");
        lastResult = false; // failure!
      }
      callback(lastResult); // send the result back
    });
  }

    var ctryiso = $("#ctry").val();
    var options = {
         types: ["geocode"]
    };
    if(ctryiso != ''){
        options.componentRestrictions= { 'country': ctryiso };        
    }
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[0], options); 


  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', processLocation);

  $('#search_form').on('submit', function (event) {
    var form = this;

    event.preventDefault(); // stop the submission

    processLocation(function (success) {
      if( success ) { // if the geocoding succeeded, submit the form
        form.submit()
      }
    });

  });
});
```

---

When the **submit form** button is pressed it will do the following (this works already):

1. Check if result is already geocoded from autosuggest click
2. If not, geocode
3. Submit the form if successful

When the **Geocode** button is pressed I want it to do the following (this doesn't work):

1. Check if result is already geocoded from autosuggest click
2. If not, geocode

---

So my question is, how can I make it so I can use the same code for both scripts without having to duplicate it twice. My idea was to do the following:

- Have a function for the "submit form" button which includes submitting the form
- Have a function for the geocode button which does not include submitting the form

I would rather use a function for each button rather than using some kind of flag, but I am completely stuck on how to implement this, every time I work on it I end up breaking the script completely. I am new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only difference is that one submits and the other does not, allow a callback to be passed into the function, and the one that submits can pass a submit to the function.

Comment: This is a little bit advanced for me, I need to do some reading on this because I dont really understand callbacks at the moment

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll demonstrate. It's a rather simple concept, really.

Comment: Um, your two forms are identical!  You cannot use an id more than once in a page.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realise. It's no issue for me to have different form names though for my usecase.

Comment: If I had realised how much of a mess your code was in, I wouldn't have volunteered to do this. However, I did, and I have. A few notes first. Don't use headings just for style! Use the appropriate markup and style with CSS.  Learn how to form an input correctly! Don't repeat IDs in a page. I'm sure I found more, but that's just off the top of my head. I don't know if my solution works in your project, but it at least demonstrates how to keep the majority of your code while doing subtly different things.  http://jsfiddle.net/H6SZ2/7/

Comment: Notice how `processLocation` only passes the anonymous function when you want to submit the form. That is an example of passing a callback.

Comment: Ok, I'm looking through the code and trying to understand it now, thank you for the help. As it stands though I have a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined which seems to stop it from working

Comment: Do you get that error in the fiddle? I ask because I wasn't. It sounds like whatever page you're running this on doesn't have jQuery, or you're trying to use `.val()` on something that isn't a jQuery object. (Keep in mind, I had to change *everything*, not just the functions at the end.)

Comment: I get it when using the first form in JSfiddle, whilst looking at the chrome console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of undefined fiddle.jshell.net/:39
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val'